# No ads, even I still don't have 200 reputation

Tags: support, advertising

OK, I may regret this, but I noticed that I have no ads on Super User, but my reputation is 186 and never was above 200. In case it matters, I have 4 other accounts with 200+ reputation.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That privilege is network-wide.